# How can I make the blade of this sword thicker?

Tags: vertices, transforms, 3d-printing

I have this part of a 3d model I bought for printing. The printed sword is about 9.5cm long (or 4 3/4 inches), but the blade is too flimsy, and doesn't hold its shape. So I want to edit the blade to make it thicker. I don't mind that it will no longer be correctly scaled to the hilt and hand, it will still serve its purpose as a display piece.

[image]

Unfortunately the rotation axes of the part are not aligned to the blade, and even if they were I'm not sure how to scale only the vertices I want.

I have created a group of all vertices that are part of the blade, and have been able to center the cursor/origin at the end of the hilt cylinder. But I've no idea what to do with it now. Grabbing the scale tool just warps the blade in weird and wonderful ways. I tried 'fatten' but that also seems axis dependent.

I have done a lot of kitbashing in Blender, but I've always found axes and how they apply to vertices too finicky. Most of the models I've worked on were a smaller scale, so minor sins were easy to hide. Could anyone point me the right way?

Comment: Perhaps share the illustrated part of your model on https://blend-exchange.com/, so folks can demonstrate how to deal with the ghastly topology .. :)

Comment: Fatten should work, but as Robin says, maybe share your file so that we can try